# Do guest passes have an expiration date?

Tags: steam

I got a TF2 guest pass last Monday, and since it's only to play for 3 days, I wanted to wait for this weekend to redeem it.

Up until 2 days ago I got the pop-up that told me to redeem it in that moment, I just closed it and it re-appeared the next day.

I wanted to activate it yesterday, but I found it no where in the Steam interface, and the pop-up hasn't appeared again.

Did I lose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>In games > Gift and Guest passes you will see an "expiration" column. So yes I guess it can expires.</strike>

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=549#expire says :

> Do gifts expire if they are not redeemed in a certain amount of time?
>
> Gifts will not expire once they have been issued. Once the gift purchase has been activated, the game is permanently subscribed to the Steam account that it was redeemed on.

Comment: Those are the games and guest passes I have to give, and I *think* that means expiration for gifting, not redeeming.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are expirations for Guest Passes.

I don't know where this expiration date is listed for the person receiving the guest pass, but for the person giving you the guest pass, the expiration date is listed on the Gifts & Guest Passes interface (Games -> Manage Gifts and Guest Passes in the Steam client's menus.)

From the [Guest Passes Guide](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8112-DFJL-4653):

> Guest passes have an expiration date
>   that is determined by the time they
>   are granted to you. To check when your
>   guest passes expire, go to Steam's
>   Games > Manage gifts & guest passes...
>   menu. If you do not give out your
>   guest passes during the determined
>   period they will expire.

Comment: This really answers if I was the one giving it out, but I was the one receiving it. Thanks though.

Comment: @JuanMichael: If you didn't accept the guest pass, it remains on the sender's account.  They can also revoke it and assign it to someone else, as long as the expiration date hasn't passed.